# One-way hash function in R

Tags: r, hash

Is there a repeatable one-way hash function in R?  I'd use `hashlib` in Python:

```
hashlib.sha224("This is my input").hexdigest()
```

Comment: Try the packages `hash` and `digest`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the `digest` pacakge installed, you can do

```
digest::digest("This is my input")
# [1] "2e936bb276abca8a9e46bd32c7bdc01e"
```

(by default the result is returned as ASCII hex values). See the `?digest` help page for a list of supported hashing algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [`digest` package](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/digest.html).