# Is there an R function to unhash data (equivalent to 'hashlib' function in Python)?

Tags: r, hash

I am trying to get an SHA-256 hash of the password. I have both the zip file where hashed data is located, and the password.

Trying to achieve something like the below in R but can't find any suitable function to programmatically retrieve the data.

```
# Declaring the Password
password = "XXXX"
data = "data.zip"

# Obtaining an SHA-256 hash of the password
import hashlib
value = hashlib.sha256(str.encode(password)).hexdigest().lower()
```

Thanks

Comment: `digest::digest` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686645/how-to-create-md5-hash-of-a-column-in-r/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782140/one-way-hash-function-in-r